# How does Google Drive prevent sharing with unauthorized users?

Tags: security, network-programming

I was just generally curious how Google tracks the users given permission to access a document and differentiates between those and other users. Any info is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive files and folders have read and write permission levels similar to most file systems:

- assigned to the individual author/owner of the file
- assigned to the domain the author/owner belongs to (typically the organization registered to use G Suite)
- assigned to the group associated with your user account on a per file basis
- assigned to the whole world

When individual users are granted access to the files (or folders), they are assigned a role and added to a group that has permission to view or edit the specific file.

If a user is accessing Google drive via an organization's G Suite account, there may be restrictions in place at the organization level that determine what type of sharing is available.  Refer to [G Suite file sharing](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en)

The Google drive Rest API documentation enumerates some of these specifics.  See ["Role" and "Type" properties on the API page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions)